# Disorted Raster Using TIN

Tags: qgis, interpolation, tin

I'm trying to create DEM based on TIN from points layer that I have.
this is how the layer looks like-
[image]

when I try to use the TIN interpolation tool I fill it like that and I use the layer extent-
[image]

as you can see, for some reason, the number of rows and columns doesn't change.
 if I keep it like that, I get '' invisible'' raster. if I change it, I  get rastes that doesn't really have the extent I want-
[image]

how can I change that? what am I missing?

Comment: Does the elevation column have data for all the rows? Have you tried using the z-coordinate, instead of elevation column? Do you have the possibility of trying the same procedure in Arcgis? and lastly, can you share the data so that anyone else can try, maybe it's an issue on your machine only?

Comment: Not that it will solve your problem but your data is in EPSG 4326 (WGS84).  Reproject your data to a Cartesian coordinate reference system like UTM and try again.